# What is the difference between the groups $PSU(N)$ and $SU(N)$?

Tags: symmetry, supersymmetry, group-theory, definition

What is the difference between the groups $PSU(N)$ and $SU(N)$? For example how is $PSU(2,2|4)$ different than $SU(2,2|4)$?

Comment: What do you mean *"what's the difference?"*? By definition, the projective (special) unitary group is the [right] quotient of the (special) unitary group by its center, so the difference is rather obvious.

Comment: Yes, could you give me more details about this or a specific reference??? To me what you said is not obvious at all. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_unitary_group) covers the most important facts, in particular, that $\mathrm{SU}(N)$ is an $N$-fold cover of its projective version, and that the projective versions of the unitary and special unitary group agree.

Comment: Thanks. But can you provide some physical intuition? People understand $SU(N)$ because of the familiarity with QCD, but not the case of $PSU(N)$.

Comment: an answer can be found at  http://www.physicsoverflow.org/26876